# var_dump выводит "NULL"

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

```
    <?php
        $rests = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `rests`");

        var_dump($rests);
    ?>
```

Не находит таблицу, даже var_dump выводит "NULL" Что это может быть?

P.S. подключение к БД работает, таблица rests существует, данные в ней есть, орфографию проверил

Comment: Вроде проблема на connect. опишите что говорит сам коннект

Comment: как уже показали ниже, $rests это не массив.

Comment: Какая версия php?

Comment: Снова "парень с ютуба" косячит)) Как написали ниже, вероятнее всего нужно просто fetch добавить после запроса к базе, чтобы отобразилось через var_dump

Comment: Ребята, скиньте пожалуйста актуального чтива на эту тему, иначе "парни с ютуба" меня скоро доведут)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```php
$rests = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `rests`");
$data = $rests->fetch_all();
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Не сработало, но теперь и оставшуюся часть сайта не выводит

Comment: @Александр вар дампить нужно было дату) мой косяк

Comment: Тот же эффект, эх(